# How Make Toolbar Tranparent ImageView with NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I want to make a transparent toolbar. I have tried making it but still failed. I wrote the XML. When scrolling, the image will go up and the toolbar will be transparent, arrow back can call the finish function.

Screenshot of toolbar:

[image: Toolbar]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000"
        app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
            android:onClick="onback" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_detail"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorSilver"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Custom toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: can you share your code by editing your question?

Comment: help me find a solution

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Coordinate layout instead of relative layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#0000"
            app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
                android:onClick="onback" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_detail"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorSilver"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```